# Removing the comment function within wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, comments

I'm using wordpress for my company website but I want to remove the comments function completely so not just by unchecking a "alow comments" within every page.

I did some googeling and the said I was supposed to remove this line of code:

```
<?php comments_template(); // Get wp-comments.php template ?>
```

And this code should be located in page.php but I'm unable to find this code.
Maybe this was a way to do it in a old version of wordpress?

Does anyknow know how I can remove it? :)

Comment: which theme are you using?

Comment: a theme called MetroStyle by OlevMedia

Comment: did you try searching all your files for "comments_template();"

Answer (score 0):

you have to remove `<?php comments_template(); ?>` in all `content*.php` in your template and all between `if ( comments_open() ) .. endif`

Answer (score 0):

Since you were not able to find `comments_template();` in your page template, check inside content template that the page uses.

The `get_template_part` function would look something like this:

```
<?php get_template_part( 'content', 'single' ); ?>
```

Join those two parameters by a dash and check inside that template (in above case, you would check content-single.php).

If you still can't find the `comments_template();`, maybe your pages are really posts, so look for that comment function inside Single Post template (single.php) and locate its content template (same way as we did with a page).